# Problems in FocusListener-Swing

Tags: java, swing

In my application i have used a Frame which consists of auto-complete details,i.e.,if we select Name,automatically details of that Name will be displayed.
For selecting name i have used a Separate textfield with Drop-down, similar to Auto-complete.

But when i go to the name section and click names using Mouse,its getting selected,the same when i did using Keyboard Navigation keys,Focus doesn't stays in Textfield,even after selecting the textfield with mouse and use Keyboard ,its not getting focus.

Hope m clear,I'm Sorry if you couldn't get what i mean ..

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) of your problem?

Comment: sorry, no, it's not clear (and that's not a problem of the language :) There are several issus which make it impossible to answer a) custom classes b) unusual event handling in those custom classes c) focusListeners are notoriously tricky, here it might be special to your concrete context. In summary: something wrong with the code you are not showing, see the other comment on how-to improve your question :-)

Comment: Pleas provide your code to get better solution.

Comment: You might be able to install a custom ``KeyboardFocusManager`` that delegates to the default one, and log stack traces of where focus is being sent and what is doing it, and find the problem that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use JComboBox rather than JTextField for Drop-Down

Use `loadCombo()` method to add names in `JComboBox`.

Then use

```
jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
Object name=jComboBox.getSelectedItem();

//Make DB connection on name and fetch the details
//Use double vector for fetching data

Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        data=getDetails();

Stsem.out.println(data);//To print data (for Confirmation that it works fine)
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,data);


private Vector<Vector<String>> getDetails(Object name) {
//DB Connections
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table");

ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
{
Vector<String> item = new Vector<String>();
item.add(rs.getString(1)); 
item.add(rs.getString(2)); 
...
itemVector.add(item);
}

/*Close the connection after use (MUST)*/
if(conn!=null)
conn.close();

return itemVector;
            }
        });
```